# RedHat installation error

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am trying to install RedHat on virtualbox running in ubuntu but it results in "drives not found error" on both RHEL 3 and Red Hat 9 versions. I have a sata hard disk and the details of my machine are Processor - Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6400  @ 2.00GHz, 2000 Mhz, IDE - Name Intel(R) ICH9M/M-E Family 4 Port SATA AHCI Controller - 2929

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. Adding a new IDE controller in Virtualbox did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurs to me that RHEL-3 and RedHat-9 doesn't support SATA drives, VirtualBox by default adds a SATA controller to the VM, you can remove this and add an IDE controller and hard drive for your VM.